# To many if statements to handle

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a sheet I want to maintain regarding progress in a evaluation project.

Current DATE (today())

Columns (cannot make a table here)

Date 1, is when the initial request has been send.
Date 2, is when the 1st reminder has been send.
Date 3, is when the 2nd reminder has been send.
Date 4, is when the evaluation has been recieved.

I want a field that gives a value when action is needed. (this is so i can assign a conditional format rule to it).
These are the action rules:
- Date 4 is empty
AND
- Date 1 is more than 7 days ago ( if(currentdate-date 1)>7, 1, 0)
(this is the easy part and now comes the part where i start getting lost)
If there is a Date 2:
- Date 2 is less then 7 days ago - NO action
- Date 2 more then 7 days ago - action needed
If there is a Date 3:
- Date 3 is less then 7 days ago - NO action
- Date 3 more then 7 days ago - action needed

In the end I just want 1 cell that said either 1 or 0 for action/no action.

I tried making 1 long string of if's but that does not work. I have tried making it in seperate cells but could not make it work.

Comment: Use an `OR` statement: `=IF(OR(currentdate-date1>7, date-date2<7, ...), 1, 0)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can nest them :) it seems easier to read if you flip the >

```
if(currentdate - date1 < 7, "No Action", if(currentdate - date2 < 7, "No Action", if(currentdate - date3 < 7, "No Action", "Action")))
```

Comment: I thank you, I am using it now. The flipping really helped!

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to use formulas. Instead of nesting lots of `If`-formulas, I would advise you to write a user defined function.

That function can be used just like any Excel-Formula, with the small exception that you need to save your workbook with an `*.xlsm` file extension.

Also note that you gave explanations on what to do if the `DateDiff` is `>7` and `<7`, but didn't mention what should be done the date is exactly 7 days in the past - therefore this isn't included in the formula below. ;)

Paste this into your "ThisWorkbook"-Module, and use `ActionRequired` just like any normal formula.

```
Public Function ActionRequired(Optional date1 As Date = 0, Optional date2 As Date = 0, Optional date3 As Date = 0, Optional date4 As Date = 0) As Boolean

If date4 = 0 And DateDiff("d", date1, Now) > 7 Then

    If Not DateDiff("d", date2, Now) < 7 Then
        ActionRequired = True
        Exit Function
    End If

    If Not DateDiff("d", date3, Now) < 7 Then
        ActionRequired = True
        Exit Function
    End If

End If

End Function
```

That's not to say that nesting `If`-excel formulas doesn't work (it does), but in my experience stuff like that is pretty prone to error, since it gets messy rather fast (in addition, your formula is stored in 100s of cells - with an UDF, its stored in exactly one place - your code - and only called in the the cells)

Comment: Ok never worked with formula's I will look into it. But for now I will use the other answer because i can use that more quickly.

Comment: np, please make sure to mark Illpratll's post as answer!